# Customising the ubuntu linux kernel

Tags: 12.04, kernel, customization

Can any one tell me how to customize the linux kernel for ubuntu package so that my kernel size can be reduced with necessary packages and the new kernel size should be very small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customization will affect just that particular version made by you. This will be your kernel compiled from source and customized. Actually if all your hardware is working with the new made kernel, you don't need to upgrade it after at all.

The description of how to do it, you can find it at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel.